# Solving for Bias in Simultaneous Equations Model without Instruments

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, bias

Suppose you have the following structural equations where wage and status are determined simultaneously and you do not have any instruments for wage or status:

$(1) \text{wage}_i = \alpha_w + \beta_w * \text{status}_i + \epsilon_i$

$(2) \text{status}_i = \alpha_s + \beta_s * \text{wage}_i + \gamma_i$

And you also have data observations of status and wage determined by the process above and run the following regression on the observed data.

$ \text{wage}^{obs}_i = \alpha_{obs} + \beta_{obs} * \text{status}^{obs}_i + \omega_i $

How do you solve for the $\beta_{obs}$ coefficient from the above regression in terms of the parameters of the structural coefficients. I have seen this done many times for cases where other exogenous variables included in the structural equations but never for this case where no exogenous variables are included.

Comment: Hi @identification_1 . I am currently having the same question. Did you already find a solution for this problem? Thanks for sharing!